# Merging multiple shapefiles into one shapefile

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, merge, union

I have 5 shapefiles in Postgres. i am trying to merge them into one shapefile but each shapefile has a different amount of columns and data types. I am aware the union and union all will not work if there are different amounts of columns and data types. they all have the same SRID

```
select * into newtable
from(select * from schools
    union all
    select * from childcare
    union all
    select * from infrastructure
    union all
    select * from nursinghomes
    union all
    select * from hospitals 
    )t;
```

I am wondering if there is work around that can merge or smash the shapefiles together similar to the merge tool in arcgis which will do this

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, do you want to merge different schema shps into one shp (before in postgres) or merge different schema postgres tables into one postgres table?

Comment: in postgres i want to merge the shapefiles into one shapefile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do your unions, each table being unionized must contain the same amount of columns with the same column names.

To simplify your statement so that you understand, I give you this example where the column names are the same:

```
select 
  id,
  geom
from nursinghomes
    union all
select 
  id,
  geom
from hospitals
```

this has the effect of removing data from both table that you may want to retain, so you could try something like this:

```
select 
  id,
  geom,
  nursinghomesname as name,
  nursinghomedoctor as misc1 
from nursinghomes
    union all
select 
  id,
  geom,
  hospitalname as name,
  '' as misc1 
from hospitals
```

Comment: ahh okay neat Il give that a try

Comment: @ ziggy I updated the answer to make the code more readable