# Can I concatenate multiple shapefiles into one using ogr2ogr?

Tags: shapefile

I know I can convert multiple shapefiles to other formats like described in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/using-ogr2ogr-to-convert-all-shapefiles-in-directory). Also, I know that I can merge multiple shapefiles into one when I have a PostGIS database like described on [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209077/merging-multiple-shapefiles-into-one-shapefile). However, I haven't found any information about merging multiple shapefiles in the command line. Is it possible? Or do I need to have a PostgreSQL with PostGIS to accomplish that?

Comment: Easy if you have the same columns for all your shapefiles. You can use `ogrmerge.py` with `-single` option https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html

Comment: Thanks, I managed to merge them by putting all the shapefiles inside the same folder and using the command `ogrmerge.py -single *.shp -o finalResultFolder/merge.shp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy if you have the same columns for all your shapefiles and GDAL/OGR installed and know how to use shell commands.

In this case, you can use `ogrmerge.py` with `-single` option. Complete documentation with some examples is available at http://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html